I got the android app crash while openUrlRequest using flutter_inappwebview: ^6.0.0
the code is
 await browser.openUrlRequest(
      urlRequest: URLRequest(url: WebUri(selectedUrl)),
      settings: InAppBrowserClassSettings(
        webViewSettings: InAppWebViewSettings(useShouldOverrideUrlLoading: true, useOnLoadResource: true, isInspectable: kDebugMode),
        browserSettings: InAppBrowserSettings(hideUrlBar: true, hideToolbarTop: GetPlatform.isAndroid),
      ),
    );

and it crashes here.
changes the version, but it's not solved in Flutter SDK 3.22.1,

Can you post a MRE?

use url launcher. As below:

Goto android manifest and Application-> queries->

 <queries>
    <intent>
        <action android:name="android.support.customtabs.action.CustomTabsService" />
    </intent>
 </queries>

Now write the code as below:
import 'package:url_launcher/url_launcher.dart';

static Future<void> _launchUrl() async {
    final Uri _url = Uri.parse('https://example.com');
    await launchUrl(_url);
    // if (!) {
    //   throw Exception('Could not launch $_url');
    // }
  }


I need to use flutter_inappwebview.

Oh i see. I misunderstood your post. Let me try again
